# Find the image of a given morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A = k[x,y]$, : $B=k[x,y,z]$,: $\varphi: A \rightarrow B/(xz - y)$, defined in a natural way ($\varphi(x) = [x], \: \varphi(y) = [y]$). The question is to find $\varphi^*(\operatorname{spec}(B/(xz - y))) \subset \operatorname{spec}(A)$.

My attempt:
Firstly, $f \in p \iff f = 0$ in $\operatorname{Fr}(B/p)$ for any prime ideal $p \in \operatorname{spec}(B)$.
Secondly, for arbitrary ring $R$, and natural map $R \rightarrow R[z]$ (our case is $R = k[x,y]$) $p^{ec} = p$ for ideals in $R$.

Now, let $p \in \operatorname{spec}(A)$. If $(x) \subset p$, then $(x) \subset q$ for all $q \in \operatorname{spec}(B)$ such that $q^c = p$. We want $xz - y = 0$ for some $q$ in $\operatorname{Fr}(B/q)$, this implies $y \in q$. Take $q = p^e$, so $(x, y) \in \varphi^*(\operatorname{spec}(B/(xz - y)))$

I'm struggling with ideals not containing $(x)$. I'll be glad to get a hint.

Comment: Honestly, I think the best thing to do here is rewrite both schemes as $\mathbb{A}^2$, then break the problem down to considering prime ideals of height 1 and 2 seperately.

Comment: @CoherentSheaf Thanks! This task was given before a lecture, where schemes are studied, but I'll try to solve it using your approach later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can be a bit more low tech about this in order to get an idea of what should happen. Think about taking points of the form $(x,xz,z)\mapsto (x,xz)$: what's in the image of this? If $x\neq 0$, then you can get any point of the form $(x,y)$ by letting $z=\frac{y}{x}$; if $x=0$, you're stuck with $(0,0)$, so the image is the nonvanishing locus of $x$ union $(0,0)$.

Now the trick is to turn this equation-solving in to algebraic geometry. One way to do this is to exploit the correspondence theorems to make our problem a little easier

> Note that there is a canonical bijection between prime ideals $P\subset k[x,y,z]/(xz-y)$ not containing $x$ and prime ideals of $$k[x,y,z]_x/(xz-y) = k[x,y,z]_x/(z-y/x) \cong k[x,y]_x,$$ so the induced map over $D(x)\subset \operatorname{Spec} A$ is an isomorphism. (Put another way, if $P\subset k[x,y,z]/(xz-y)$ is a prime ideal not containing $x$, then $P^{ec}=P$.) For ideals containing $x$, note that there's canonical bijection between the prime ideals of $k[x,y,z]/(xz-y)$ containing $x$ and the prime ideals of $k[x,y,z]/(x,xz-y)\cong k[y,z]/(y)\cong k[z]$, and the induced map $k[x,y]\to k[z]$ is $x,y\mapsto 0$. Therefore the only prime ideal which contains $x$ and is in the image of the map on spectra is $(x,y)$.

Comment: Thank you! Amazing that we even don't have to know what prime ideals look like

Comment: You're welcome! Images are really a time to do geometry :). Also, after you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).